# Bash Awk: Median over windows with start and stop positions

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file that looks like below. First column is location, second is position and third is value.

```
1 10 200
1 11 150
1 12 300
2 13 400
2 14 100
2 15 250
3 16 200
3 17 200
3 18 350
3 19 150
...
```

I would like to calculate the median of the value field over a certain window. For example lets say a window size of 4 rows. Below is the expected result for the sample data above:

```
1 2 10 13 250
2 3 14 17 200
...
```

For every window (4 rows), the first value (within window) of first column, last value (within window) of the first column, first value of the second column, last value of the second column and the median of third column is reported.

I have got it partially working. The script below prints last position of column 1, last position of column 2 and mean.

```
win=4
cat file.txt | awk -v win="$win" '{sum+=$3} (NR%win)==0 {print $1,$2,sum/win;sum=0}'

2 13 262.5
3 17 187.5
...
```

How do I get the initial positions within each window and median?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{r=(NR-1)%4; a[r]=$3} 
   r==0{f1=$1; s1=$2} 
   r==3{asort(a); print f1,$1,s1,$2,(a[2]+a[3])/2; delete a}' file

1 2 10 13 250
2 3 14 17 200
```

note that delete is not really necessary since the values are overwritten at each window computation...

you can parameterize window size, need to handle odd/even

```
$ awk -v w=5 '{r=(NR-1)%w; a[r]=$3} 
          r==0{f1=$1; s1=$2} 
      r==(w-1){asort(a); 
               print f1,$1,s1,$2,(w%2?a[int(w/2)+1]:(a[w/2]+a[w/2+1])/2); 
               delete a}' file

1 2 10 14 200
2 3 15 19 200
```

doesn't handle if the last window is not full size

Comment: thats cool! exactly what I was looking for. Can a check be put in to ignore/skip windows less than window-size?

Comment: This will ignore that last partial block, for some additional logic create an `END` block and check whether r is less than (w-1), which will mean a partial last block and report accordingly.